# I want to enable users use their Spoitfy ID and Secret in Shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, spotify, shinyapps

I want to build an app that analyzes Spotify data. However, I want to let users use their own Spotify client id and client secret to access the Spotify API. Therefore, I have created input areas for the client id and client secret in the app. Then, there is an "Authenticate" button, which triggers the authentication of the id and secret. In the script, I have written an authentication function, which is run when I click the "Authenticate" button.

However, when I run the app and enter my client id and secret, as a user is expected to, and then try to fetch some data, I get the error message below in my console:

```
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:3991
Request failed [400]. Retrying in 1.7 seconds...
Request failed [400]. Retrying in 1.8 seconds...
Warning: Error in get_spotify_access_token: 
  167: stop
  166: get_spotify_access_token
  165: get_related_artists
  164: artists_popularity [C:\Users\IFEANYI\Documents\SpotifyNet\testAPP/app.R#58]
  163: <reactive:bar_plot> [C:\Users\IFEANYI\Documents\SpotifyNet\testAPP/app.R#199]
  147: bar_plot
  146: eventReactiveValueFunc [C:\Users\IFEANYI\Documents\SpotifyNet\testAPP/app.R#201]
  102: plot_react
  101: renderPlotly [C:\Users\IFEANYI\Documents\SpotifyNet\testAPP/app.R#206]
  100: func
   97: shinyRenderWidget
   96: func
   83: renderFunc
   82: output$plot
    1: runApp
```

But when I, as a default, include my Spotify client id and secret in the Shiny app script, it works just fine. But that way, users will be using my API tokens to get data, which I do not want. I want them to be able to use their own credentials to access the API. I have included here a reprex of the app, in case anyone is willing and kindhearted enough to help me troubleshoot this problem. Thanks in advance of your help.

Reprex:

```
library(shiny)
library(spotifyr)
library(plotly)

ui <- fluidPage(title = "Bar Plot",
#h2(p(id = "question","What does this app do?")),
#actionButton("button","Answer"),

            # javascript code to answer question
           # includeScript("Answer.js"),
            
            # add css
           # includeCSS("styles.css"),
              
            
            
            sidebarLayout(
              sidebarPanel(textInput("id","Enter Client ID"),
                           textInput("secret","Enter Client Secret"),
                           actionButton("auth","Authenticate"),br(),hr(),
                           textInput("text","Enter Artist's ID"),id = "sidebar",
                           actionButton("click","Get data"),
                           width = 3),
              mainPanel(fluidRow(column(6,plotlyOutput("plot",width = "105%",height = "400px")))
            )))

    server <- function(input,output,session){
    
    # set up Spotify API credentials environment
    authentication <- function(id, secret) {
    
    client_ID <- as.character(id)
    client_secret <- as.character(secret)
    
    # authenticate the spotify client side
    Sys.setenv(SPOTIFY_CLIENT_ID = client_ID)
    Sys.setenv(SPOTIFY_CLIENT_SECRET = client_secret)
    
    access_token <- get_spotify_access_token()
    
    return(access_token)
    }
    
    # validate API credentials
    authenticate <- reactive(authentication(input$id,input$secret))
    
    validation <- eventReactive(input$auth,{
    authenticate()})
    
    artists_popularity <- function(artist_id){
    # get related artists
    related_artists <- get_related_artists(id = artist_id,
    include_meta_info = TRUE)
    
    # get other artists that are related to the 
    # artists that are related to the main artist
    other_related <- c()
    for(i in 1:nrow(related_artists$artists)){
      result <- get_related_artists(id = related_artists$artists[["id"]][i],
                                    include_meta_info = TRUE)
      other_related <- append(other_related,result)
    }
    
    # create nodes data.frame
    nodes <- data.frame(
      id = c(1:400),
      node = c(other_related[[1]]$name,
               other_related[[2]]$name,
               other_related[[3]]$name,
               other_related[[4]]$name,
               other_related[[5]]$name,
               other_related[[6]]$name,
               other_related[[7]]$name,
               other_related[[8]]$name,
               other_related[[9]]$name,
               other_related[[10]]$name,
               other_related[[11]]$name,
               other_related[[12]]$name,
               other_related[[13]]$name,
               other_related[[14]]$name,
               other_related[[15]]$name,
               other_related[[16]]$name,
               other_related[[17]]$name,
               other_related[[18]]$name,
               other_related[[19]]$name,
               other_related[[20]]$name),
      
      label = c(other_related[[1]]$name,
                other_related[[2]]$name,
                other_related[[3]]$name,
                other_related[[4]]$name,
                other_related[[5]]$name,
                other_related[[6]]$name,
                other_related[[7]]$name,
                other_related[[8]]$name,
                other_related[[9]]$name,
                other_related[[10]]$name,
                other_related[[11]]$name,
                other_related[[12]]$name,
                other_related[[13]]$name,
                other_related[[14]]$name,
                other_related[[15]]$name,
                other_related[[16]]$name,
                other_related[[17]]$name,
                other_related[[18]]$name,
                other_related[[19]]$name,
                other_related[[20]]$name),
      
      popularity = c(c(other_related[[1]]$popularity,
                       other_related[[2]]$popularity,
                       other_related[[3]]$popularity,
                       other_related[[4]]$popularity,
                       other_related[[5]]$popularity,
                       other_related[[6]]$popularity,
                       other_related[[7]]$popularity,
                       other_related[[8]]$popularity,
                       other_related[[9]]$popularity,
                       other_related[[10]]$popularity,
                       other_related[[11]]$popularity,
                       other_related[[12]]$popularity,
                       other_related[[13]]$popularity,
                       other_related[[14]]$popularity,
                       other_related[[15]]$popularity,
                       other_related[[16]]$popularity,
                       other_related[[17]]$popularity,
                       other_related[[18]]$popularity,
                       other_related[[19]]$popularity,
                       other_related[[20]]$popularity)),
      
      followers = c(c(other_related[[1]]$followers.total,
                      other_related[[2]]$followers.total,
                      other_related[[3]]$followers.total,
                      other_related[[4]]$followers.total,
                      other_related[[5]]$followers.total,
                      other_related[[6]]$followers.total,
                      other_related[[7]]$followers.total,
                      other_related[[8]]$followers.total,
                      other_related[[9]]$followers.total,
                      other_related[[10]]$followers.total,
                      other_related[[11]]$followers.total,
                      other_related[[12]]$followers.total,
                      other_related[[13]]$followers.total,
                      other_related[[14]]$followers.total,
                      other_related[[15]]$followers.total,
                      other_related[[16]]$followers.total,
                      other_related[[17]]$followers.total,
                      other_related[[18]]$followers.total,
                      other_related[[19]]$followers.total,
                      other_related[[20]]$followers.total))
    )
    
    # remove duplicate nodes and labels in data frame
    
    nodes <- distinct(nodes,node,label,popularity,followers,.keep_all = T)
    
    # create new data.frame for bar plot tooltip
    nodes_df <- data.frame(
      Artist = reorder(nodes$node,+nodes$popularity),
      Popularity = nodes$popularity
    )
    
    # select top twenty most popular nodes
    nodes_df <- head(nodes_df,20)
    
    # create random color fill options
    fill <- c("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H")
    rand_fill <- sample(fill,size = 1)
    
    # plot top twenty most popular nodes
    ggnodes <- nodes_df |> 
      ggplot()+aes(x = Artist,y = Popularity,fill = Artist)+
      geom_bar(stat = "identity")+coord_flip()+
      ggtitle("Top 20 Most Popular Artists")+
      labs(x = "Artists")+scale_fill_viridis(discrete = T,option = rand_fill)+
      scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0))+
      theme(axis.ticks = element_blank(),
            legend.position = "none",
            axis.text = element_text(size = 10,face = "bold"),
            plot.title = element_text(size = 12,face = "bold",hjust = 0.5),
            axis.title.x = element_text(size = 12,face = "bold"),
            axis.title.y = element_text(hjust = 0.8,size = 12,face = "bold"))
    
    g <- ggnodes |> ggplotly(tooltip = c("x","y")) # show only x and y aesthetic values
    
    
    return(g)
    }
    
    id_input <- reactive({as.character(input$text)})
    bar_plot <- reactive({artists_popularity(id_input())})
    related_network <- reactive({related_artists_network(id_input())})
    plot_react <- eventReactive(input$click,{bar_plot()})
    network_react <- eventReactive(input$click,{related_network()})
    
    output$plot <- renderPlotly({
    plot_react()
    })
    
    }
    
    shinyApp(ui = ui,server = server)
```

Comment: I would print what you think the "authentication" is receiving. I am inclined to think you are getting the error as the function is giving the API: Username="Username", Password="Password" vs API Username=Username, Password=Password. Thoughts?

Comment: Note: the user also need to add the redirect uri to the app at their dashboard.

Comment: I printed out the authentication, and it is something totally different from the input values.

Comment: I cannot explain why the printed values are different from the input values. . . it's weird.

Comment: Sounds like we have pinpointed where the problem, is would be happy to help, with your issue, but you may need to revise your question with the code in question and what your output is so that we can help you trouble shoot.

Comment: Hi @jcruzer, thanks a lot for your help. I figured out that those characters are actually the validation reference id, which indicate that my client id and client secret have actually been validated. Hence, it is the output that is printed out. Thanks again!